# How to cache an image from firebase storage in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrote a flutter app that trying to cache an image from firebase storage using **cached_network_image** when the app is staring, but I'm keep getting the same error when I try to wait until the image is done loading and I can use her. if someone know what is my problem please let me know.

this is the mention error:

> The argument type 'Future<'dynamic'>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Future<'dynamic'>>'.

this is my code that supposed to cache the image:

```
/// imports

class ClientHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ClientHomePage({Key? key, this.uid}) : super(key: key);
  final uid;
  @override
  _ClientHomePageState createState() => _ClientHomePageState(uid);
}

class _ClientHomePageState extends State<ClientHomePage> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late final uid;
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  bool isAppBar = true;
  _ClientHomePageState(this.uid);

  late List<Widget> pages;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pages = <Widget>[
      const HomePageC(),
      const SearchPageC(),
      AccountPageC(
        uid: uid,
      ),
    ];
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => cachedProfilePic(uid));
  }

  Future cachedProfilePic(uid) async {
    String url = await getStorageImage(uid, "/profile-pic.png");
    await Future.wait(cacheImage(context, url)); // here I am getting the error
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       // all of my code...
    );
  }
}
```

this is the helping functions that the other code is using:

```
// imports...

Future<String> getStorageImage(String uid, String imageName) async {
  String url = await FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref(uid)
      .child("/" + imageName)
      .getDownloadURL();
  return url;
}

Future cacheImage(BuildContext context, String url) => precacheImage(
      CachedNetworkImageProvider(url),
      context,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

this widget is for fetching, caching, and presenting an image from the network.

CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: '**your image link here**',)

Comment: where do you want me to put it, I don't really understand.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are already using it, I didn't notice, really sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter `Future.wait` is used to await and return multiple futures, why not just await the method call?

```dart
await cacheImage(context, url);
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/wait.html